# How make snapshot of dedicated server?

Tags: backup, disk-image, snapshot

What software or utility can help make a snapshot of a production Ubuntu system with all utilities and parameters? I would like to be able to simply restore this image with all data and statements, when it's needed.

I'm looking for something like TimeShift, but without GUI.

Comment: [Clonezilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clonezilla)? (That is, if you are looking for a full system backup which can be restored on bare metal.)

Comment: For clonezilla backup System need to be poweroff, im looking some solution without shutdown, in live mode.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/306913/full-disk-imaging-when-machine-is-running